# Tuning AWS Apache Server

Tags: apache, performance, amazon-ec2

I am trying to tune my AWS apache server. I have looked in:

```
$: httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

And I cannot find this section to edit:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers            10
    MinSpareServers         10
    MaxSpareServers         25
    ServerLimit             128
    MaxClients              128
    MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
```

Where will I find the above settings if they are not in: `httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: What OS is this? I recommend `cd`ing to the `httpd` directory and typing: `grep -r StartServers *` to find the file.

Comment: I am using a AWS LAMP stack running wordpress. Apache is using the prefork module. When I visit the file httpd/conf/httpd.conf everything is in the file with the exception of the <IfModule prefork.c> settings as mentioned above. There are no settings at all of that type. Can I just add them? or will they be in a different file elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Be sure the prefork module is enabled ( Unless you disabled it, it's enabled by default ).

The section you're looking for is in the prefork configuration file, which is in this case, in the enabled modules directory:

```
   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how apache was compiled. If apache was compiled with mod_event instead of prefork that section might not exist in the apache httpd.conf file. On redhat/centos distros the default location for httpd.conf file is in /etc/httpd/conf. On debian/ubuntru distros you will find httpd.conf in /etc/apache2

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors which impact apache performance.

> 1. Tune JVM
> 2. Log rotation policy
> 3. Tune linux kernal parameters
> 4. Tune apache MPM

I assumed you have done first 3 steps and want to understand about 4th.

Step 4. check which MPM your are using with command:

```
[root@mohitm ~]# apachectl -V|grep "Server MPM:"
Server MPM:     prefork
[root@mohitm ~]#
```

**To locate the httpd config file**

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

#

```
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      16
MinSpareServers   10
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      5024
MaxClients       5024
MaxRequestsPerChild     10000
</IfModule>
```

#

Comment: I know that I need to edit <IfModule prefork.c> but the file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf does not contain it. Where else might I find it?

Comment: find . -type f -name 'httpd.conf'; if not working then share O.S. version

Comment: got your query, edited solution. $ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

Answer (score 0):

The Apache main configuration file on Amazon Linux:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Other configuration loaded files:

```
- conf.modules.d/*.conf
- conf.d/*.conf
```

I could not find  section, then i´ve added to the main file and solve my problem.